# how to display contplaceholder in the center of the browser

Tags: asp.net

can somebody tell me how can i open my contentplaceholder in the center of the browser.

Answer (score 1):

The `contentplaceholder` itself does not render any html. You can however put a div around the `contentplaceholder` in your masterpage and assign any css style to it.

In order to center a div in css you need to use

```
margin-left: auto; 
margin-right: auto;
```

Hope it helps

Comment: i have tried this but no luck

Comment: @sumit try and show some code so we can figure out what is wrong.

Comment: there is nothing different in the code i have used a div outside contentplaceholder and the styles are the same as given by you

Comment: Well what happens? In which way it is not working?